# How to use google directions API in MAUI App?

Tags: google-maps-api-3, maui, mobile-application

How to use Google Map Route/Direction APIs in MAUI App?
Is it possible to use the same API key from https://console.cloud.google.com/apis/credentials?project=xxxxxxxxx ?
Or is it a paid service? We need to show the shortest route in the MAUI app. So how can we achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the same API key for multiple APIs. However, for security purposes and setting API key restrictions, it's recommended to use a separate API key for each, check out the API key security docs here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/api-security-best-practices

You can use the Directions API and/or Distance matrix API for this purpose:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/directions
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/distance-matrix

Directions API will give you the quickest full route and the Distance Matrix API will give you the distance and duration of routes.

If you wish to use the Browser/JS version of these APIs, check out these docs here:
https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/directions

For MAUI specific docs, take a look here:
[https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/map#distance:~:text=map%20app%20with-,directions,-The%20native%20maps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/controls/map#distance:%7E:text=map%20app%20with-,directions,-The%20native%20maps)

However, if you wish you can use a Web Service API within the mobile application. You will have to set up a proxy server or obfuscation for full API key security:
https://developers.google.com/maps/api-security-best-practices#ip-address-best-practices-table

Comment: thanks for the reply. When I try to configure, its displaying a screen for Account Information and  after that  asking for the  Credit/debit card details .  Before purchasing any subscription, need to do a trial with limited API calls..  Is it not possible ?

Comment: Google Maps Platform is now 'pay as you go', you will have to add your card details to get your API key. However, you get $200 of maps monthly credits. You can use daily quota limits to limit the requests:

Comment: Hi JummyP, I tried MapBox map with MAUI app. But its not working with maui. Any samples solution available for the same ?